# Using the new cross-referencing properties

Tags: cross-referencing, best-practices

I'm looking into the new property system (see `texdoc ltproperties-doc` or [online](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltproperties-doc.pdf)) but have an issue when referencing unknown labels.

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023/11/01]
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{abc}

\RecordProperties{seq:xyz}{label,page} % save label & page

This one is defined: \RefProperty{seq:xyz}{label} on page \RefProperty{seq:xyz}{page}

This one is not defined: \RefProperty{unknown}{label} on page \RefProperty{unknown}{page} (with default value: \RefProperty[??]{unknown}{page})

\label{seq:abc}
Old style: defined \ref{seq:abc} on \pageref{seq:abc} and undefined \ref{unknown2} on \pageref{unknown2}

\end{document}
```

First run:
[image: first run]

Relevant part of log:

```
No file property_test.aux.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `seq:abc' on page 1 undefined on input line 16.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `seq:abc' on page 1 undefined on input line 16.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `unknown2' on page 1 undefined on input line 16.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `unknown2' on page 1 undefined on input line 16.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./property_test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
```

Subsequent runs:
[image: second run]

log:

```
(./property_test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Reference `unknown2' on page 1 undefined on input line 16.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `unknown2' on page 1 undefined on input line 16.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./property_test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

Referencing unknown labels produces no warnings in the log, and typeset as page 0 unless you set a local default value. Is this a bug, or (perhaps more likely) am I using them incorrectly?

Also, the documentation has a star by `\RefProperty`, but using `\RefProperty*` yields an error (`Use of \??? doesn't match its definition`), so I am unsure what that star signifies.

Comment: I can't test now, but the reference is expandable and that means it can't generate warnings. You have to setup such warnings explicitly (there is a command).

Comment: Aha, thanks Ulrike! I'll write up a short example answer but will hold off on accepting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Ulrike Fischer's comment, creating a command that checks for the property and issues a warning appears to work (updated per @David Carlisle):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023/11/01]
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\MyRef[2]{%
    \RefProperty[%
        \textbf{??}% default output
        \RefUndefinedWarn{#1}{#2}%
    ]{#1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{abc}

\RecordProperties{seq:xyz}{label,page}

Using MyRef: defined \MyRef{seq:xyz}{label} on page \MyRef{seq:xyz}{page} and undefined \MyRef{unknown}{label} on page \MyRef{unknown}{page}

\end{document}
```

First run:
[image: first run]

Second run:
[image: second run]

Adds regular warnings like ``` LaTeX Warning: Reference ``unknown' on page 1 undefined on input line 17 ``` to the log, and the known reference shows up fine in subsequent runs.

Better methods welcome :)

Comment: You don't need the If test, the warn command only warns if a warning is needed

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand\MyRef{mm}{\RefProperty[\RefUndefinedWarn{#1}{#2}\textbf{??}]{#1}{#2}}`

Comment: Thanks David, in an earlier version it seemed to warn regardless of the check, but perhaps that was in the expl3 version of similar code I was testing? I don't have it any more, so I can't check exactly what went wrong, though..

Comment: If you also move it into the optional argument it's only ever called in the ?? case so that avoids another internal test for defined. Also NewDocumentCommand rather than newcommand makes it a `\protected` robust command so safer in  some contexts. But Ulrike's the expert here do whatever she says:-)