# "Label multiply defined" with new cross-referencing properties

Tags: cross-referencing, expl3, best-practices

When recording multiple different properties (see `texdoc ltproperties-doc` or [online](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltproperties-doc.pdf)) for the same label, warnings are issued. I am not able to record all properties at the same time (some must be recorded before the main body of an environment, and some after; FOO below is a stand-in for a unique "id" of each use of the environment).

The documents mention that this will happen "if both `\label{ABC}` and `\RecordProperties{ABC}{page}` are used", but it happens even without using a `\label`.

What is the best way to avoid these warnings?

Possibly related to [my earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/701035/using-the-new-cross-referencing-properties).

MVE:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2023/11/01]
\documentclass{article}

\NewProperty{property-a}{now}{}{a}
\NewProperty{property-b}{now}{}{b}

\begin{document}

\section{abc}

\RecordProperties{FOO}{property-a}

% stuff happens

\RecordProperties{FOO}{property-b}

Referring to them is fine: \RefProperty{FOO}{property-a} and \RefProperty{FOO}{property-b}

\end{document}
```

This will result in the log containing:

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `FOO' multiply defined.

LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels.
```

And the aux:

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}abc}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\new@label@record{FOO}{{property-a}{a}}
\new@label@record{FOO}{{property-b}{b}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Comment: That's expected, if you need them both properties under the same label, you should use `\RecordProperties{FOO}{property-a,property-b}`. If they can't go on the same place for some reason, you'll need a different label. You can create an internal derived one, e.g. `prefix/FOO`.

Comment: you are recording the same label twice, and so you have multiplied labels. That is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\RecordProperties` record the state/values of selected properties at a specific "location" in your document. If you use the command twice you have two locations and so should use two distinct "location names". The code doesn't really care if there is stuff in between or which properties you record.

That referencing works in your example is due to implementation details and is not something you should rely on (and can easily break if in your code you decide later to extend the list of properties).

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewProperty{property-a}{now}{}{a}
\NewProperty{property-b}{now}{}{b}

\begin{document}

\section{abc}

\RecordProperties{LOC1}{property-a}

% stuff happens

\RecordProperties{LOC2}{property-b}

Referring to them is fine: \RefProperty{LOC1}{property-a} and \RefProperty{LOC2}{property-b}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it working by using a suffix on my labels so I have the id while they remain unique. Perhaps the documentation could be clarified on this point (the snippet I quoted reads to me as if the problem is the interaction between the old and new label system, not the uniquess of label names)

Comment: I must say while I could imaging people trying to use both `\label{foo}` and `\RecordProperties{foo}` (and a different implementation could even allow that) I didn't imagine that someone would use `\RecordProperties` twice with the same label. I mean you wouldn't use \label twice either.

Comment: I basically misunderstood the uniqueness constraint as being label + property instead of just label